# How to pass a struct array to another struct array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

I am trying to pass a struct array to another without success.

```
s(1).f = (1:3);
s(2).f = (4:6);
s(3).f = (7:9);

q(1).n = 'nameA';
q(2).n = 'nameB';
q(3).n = 'nameC';
q(3).f = [];

q.f = s.f
```

The field `n` shouldn't be modified.

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign each field of an array of structs directly to a cell array and then you can use `deal` to convert a struct to a cell array:

```
s(1).f = (1:3);
s(2).f = (4:6);
s(3).f = (7:9);

q(1).n = 'nameA';
q(2).n = 'nameB';
q(3).n = 'nameC';

c = cell(3,1);
[c{:}] = deal(s.f);
[q.f] = c{:};
```

[Here is a good article on this sort of thing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/01/24/deal-or-no-deal/#9)

**Edit:**
Or as [Shai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1714410/shai) points out you can just go

```
[q.f] = s.f
```

Comment: while you are at it, why not just `[q.f] = s.f`?

Comment: Thank you all for your help! Shai´s edit works great. 
But your suggestion with `deal`command doesn´t work. The error message is:
_"The left hand side has c{:} inside brackets, which requires that c be defined, so that the number of expected results can be computed"_

Comment: You are right, I corrected it. Although obviously you should use Shai's edit rather.

Comment: Is there also a way, to pass more than one arrays? Suppose, there is also `s(1).fNew` and I wouldlike to pass the arrays `s.f`and `s.fNew` to struct `q`so that it becomes `q.n`, `q.f` and `q.fNew` ? This would be great!

Comment: @Shai, maybe you have an idea? Thx!

Comment: @Massoud what's wrong with '[q.f]=s.f;' '[q.fNew]=s.fNew;'? If this is a new question - post it as such.

Comment: @Shai, I just was curious how I can solve this, when I have a lot more fields.

Comment: @Dan, may you please explain what the last two code lines of your answer do? It´s a litte bit confusing for me when to use the comma separated help list `[]` and why you access `c`with the value-operator `{}`instead of the cell-field-operator `()`. Thx!

Comment: Looks like you don't actually need the `deal` at all. I can't explain it much better than that article. Basically `c{:}` gives you a comma separated list of variables, putting `[]` on the left hand side of the equation is required matlab syntax when there is more than one variable on the lhs.

Comment: Thank you, yes I agree now! The same counts for `s.f`, which also delivers a comma separated list (CSL). The `[]` on lhs in combination with a CSL on the rhs is the replacement syntax for `deal()`command since Matlab version 7.

Comment: @Dan @Shai Worth noting the `[q.f] = s.f` notation only works if `q` is preallocated to the correct size. If `q` has not been previously defined, this approach will only define `q` as `s(1).f`

Answer (score 2):

How about [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html)

```
q = arrayfun( @(x,y) setfield( x, 'f', y.f ), q, s );
```

Apparently [`setfield`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setfield.html) is only for setting one struct element in struct array -- thus the `arrayfun`.

**EDIT:**
a much better answer given by [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15135536/1714410).

Comment: Can you apply this without knowing the name of 'f' and multiple fields like 'f'? So add all fields from s to q?

Comment: @Leo you can apply the method from [Dan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15135536/1714410) only loop on all fields using `fieldnames`.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to make this suggestion by Shai more visible because it’s easier to read.

`[q.f] = s.f`

Answer (score 1):

Though I'd say [@Dan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133169/matlab-how-to-pass-a-struct-array-to-another-struct-array/15135536#15135536) is pretty canon for this question, I'd like to present an alternative:

```
s(1).f = (1:3);
s(2).f = (4:6);
s(3).f = (7:9);

[q(1:length(s)).f] = s.f;
```

Though slightly more verbose than the `[q.f] = s.f` syntax, it has the advantage of functioning as expected even if `q` has not been preallocated to the correct size to be a copy of `s`.

For example:

```
s(1).f = (1:3);
s(2).f = (4:6);
s(3).f = (7:9);

[q.f] = s.f;
```

Returns `q.f` as a `1x1 struct` equal to `s(1).f`